# Как управлять прозрачность view в рантайме?

Tags: android

существует ли способ управлять прозрачностью в рантайме, прямо из кода?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Начиная с 11 версии API, вы можете использовать [setAlpha](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAlpha%28float%29).

Если нужно для более старых версий, то вам поможет [NineOldAndroids](http://nineoldandroids.com/)